# Space between words tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

[image]I'm working with booktabs package. My goal is to get the same space between each word.

For example: LaTeX TikZ, tabular myframed titleps. \
**Not like this one**: LaTeX~~~~~TikZ,~~~~~tabular~~myframed~~~titleps .

Code sample:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=4.50cm, right=4.50cm, top=3.50cm, bottom=3.50cm]{geometry}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
    \renewcommand\quote{\list{}{\leftmargin=10pt\rightmargin=0pt}\item[]}  {\endlist}
        \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} 
    \newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!ht]
 \ra{2}
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
 \ignorespaces
 {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
 \begin{tabular}{m{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.8pt}
                m{\dimexpr.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}
                m{\dimexpr.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}}\toprule 

 \textbf{Item 1} &\textbf{Item2}& \textbf{Item3 someLongerWord}\\ \midrule
 \textbf{SubItem1 some text someLongerWord}\rr  & Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem  stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz    pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. & Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym.        
 \\
 \addlinespace[4pt] \midrule

 \textbf{SubItem2 some text} & Przeciwstawne wyobrażenia i~pojęcia występują razem i~mogą wzajemnie siebie zastępować. & Pogardzany nauczyciel wychowania fizycznego reprezentuje w~pamięci uwielbianego nauczyciela sztuki.\\ 
 \addlinespace[4pt] \midrule 

 \textbf{Reprezentacja przez analogię bądź aluzję}\rr& Części obiektu bądź pamięci reprezentują całość. Podobne wyobrażenia są~wzajemnie swobodnie wymienianie. & Wyobrażenie huśtawki reprezentuje czas spędzony w dzieciństwie na zabawie z~ojcem.
 \\\addlinespace[14pt] \midrule 
 \textbf{Płynność form}\rr& Wyobrażenia wrażeń zmysłowych odpowiadają słowom czy pojęciom. & Uczucie dreszczy z zimna reprezentuje gniew mężczyzny, który umówił się na randkę w ciemno i~czeka w padającym śniegu na~kobietę, która nie przychodzi.
 \\ \addlinespace[4pt]\midrule 
 \textbf{No Time At All someLongerWord}\rr& Brak logicznego czy czasowego następstwa. Przeszłość, teraźniejszość a~nawet przyszłość stanowią jedną całość. & Obecny mąż pojawia się we~śnie odnoszącym się do~wcześniejszego etapu życia żony.
 \\
 \bottomrule
 \addlinespace[10pt]
%
 \end{tabular}}
 \small\caption{\small Charakterystyczne cechy poznawcze procesu pierwotnego}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Getting justified text in narrow columns is a difficult task; but you get equal spaces in each line, not at all similar to your fake example. Of course there's no way to get the same spaces in *all* lines, unless you use `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the text in the columns is stretching and the inter-word spacing is uneven; the problem is caused by the presence of too long words for the width of the columns declared. One possible solution would be to set each column to be `\raggedright`, this will cause the text to be ragged right but will prevent hyphenation.

Another option would be to load the ragged2e package ans set each column to be `\justifying`; long words will still cause problems if LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate them so you will have to manually introduce hyphenation point for these cases (see the fictitious hyphenation point that I manually used in `someLongerWo\-rd`):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=4.50cm, right=4.50cm, top=3.50cm, bottom=3.50cm]{geometry}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
    \renewcommand\quote{\list{}{\leftmargin=10pt\rightmargin=0pt}\item[]}  {\endlist}
        \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} 
    \newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!ht]
 \ra{2}
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
 \ignorespaces
 {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
 \begin{tabular}{>{\justifying\arraybackslash\noindent}m{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.8pt}
                >{\justifying\arraybackslash\noindent}m{\dimexpr.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}
                >{\justifying\arraybackslash\noindent}m{\dimexpr.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}}\toprule 

 \textbf{Item 1} &\textbf{Item2}& \textbf{Item3 someLongerWo\-rd}\\ \midrule
 \noindent\textbf{SubItem1 some text someLongerWord}  & Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem  stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz    pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. & Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym.        
 \\
 \addlinespace[4pt] \midrule

 \textbf{SubItem2 some text} & Przeciwstawne wyobrażenia i~pojęcia występują razem i~mogą wzajemnie siebie zastępować. & Pogardzany nauczyciel wychowania fizycznego reprezentuje w~pamięci uwielbianego nauczyciela sztuki.\\ 
 \addlinespace[4pt] \midrule 

 \textbf{Reprezentacja przez analogię bądź aluzję}\rr& Części obiektu bądź pamięci reprezentują całość. Podobne wyobrażenia są~wzajemnie swobodnie wymienianie. & Wyobrażenie huśtawki reprezentuje czas spędzony w dzieciństwie na zabawie z~ojcem.
 \\\addlinespace[14pt] \midrule 
 \textbf{Płynność form}\rr& Wyobrażenia wrażeń zmysłowych odpowiadają słowom czy pojęciom. & Uczucie dreszczy z zimna reprezentuje gniew mężczyzny, który umówił się na randkę w ciemno i~czeka w padającym śniegu na~kobietę, która nie przychodzi.
 \\ \addlinespace[4pt]\midrule 
 \textbf{No Time At All someLongerWord}\rr& Brak logicznego czy czasowego następstwa. Przeszłość, teraźniejszość a~nawet przyszłość stanowią jedną całość. & Obecny mąż pojawia się we~śnie odnoszącym się do~wcześniejszego etapu życia żony.
 \\
 \bottomrule
 \addlinespace[10pt]
%
 \end{tabular}}
 \small\caption{\small Charakterystyczne cechy poznawcze procesu pierwotnego}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: NO, my gol is to get rid of space between word's. If you have a sentence inside of a table for example: Lorem Ipsum dolor sit I love Latex, but I hate table - the spacing between words is the same.

Comment: I my table, showed in question i have something like this:  Lorem Ipsum~~~~dolor~~sit~~I~love~~Latex,~~~~but~I~~hate table. [~ sign is a space. ~~~ is 3more times space than ~]. I ask You, how to squezze this space, that I will recive same "step"

Comment: @DanielMiliński my solution does exactly that, but the text gets ragged right. Do you want something different?

Comment: @DanielMiliński I've updated my answer with a possible solution. Please let me know if something like that is what you need.